# Не загружается надстройки VSTO Excel при открытых других файлах EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel

Друзья, столкнулся с непонятной проблемой.  Есть надстройка VSTO Excel (шаблон), и она вполне сносно работает и загружается и тд. Однако, если в момент запуска надстройки открыт любой другой файл EXCEL, то надстройка не запускается. При этом это актуально только при повторном запуске надстройки, первый раз запускается отменно. Т.е. у юзера открыт любой файл EXCEL - он открывает надстройку первый раз и все ок, после этого он закрывает и снова открывает надстройку и всё умирает.     Работа надстройки восстанавливается после закрытия всех остальных файлов EXCEL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, это конечно не совсем решение той проблемы о которой я говорил, однако подобный подход к смене архитектуры проекта способен помочь.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54881625/vsto-excel-template-are-not-loaded-when-other-excel-files-are-open/54883054?noredirect=1#comment96555716_54883054